# Pie Highchart remove path to description

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I have searched everywhere but can't seem to find the solution.

In Highcharts specifically the pie chart, there are lines extruding from the chart to the description of each series.

How do I remove these lines, or exclude them from being generated.

I basically just want the chart and descriptions but no `<path>` elements to the description.

Solution:

`pie: {
      dataLabels: {
                   connectorWidth: 0
                  }
      }`

Comment: It would be better to show what have you done.

Comment: Used the normal code of a pie chart, I just want a option to disable path generation. There are solutions which deletes the path, but you then require the path id before it can be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This path is called `connector`, and descriptions in Highcharts terms are `dataLabels`. Now, with that knowledge, you can simply set `dataLabels.connectorWidth = 0` to disable those lines, without removing anything manually. See [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#series<pie>.dataLabels.connectorWidth).

Comment: You sir are a genius. Both solution work, but yours is much easier to implement.

Answer (score 1):

The paths at least meet the following criteria: 1) fill is none and 2) stroke-width is 1. Although other elements may also meet these criteria, perhaps you can start from here:

```
$("path[fill='none'][stroke-width=1]").hide();
```

Additionally, you can also do

```
$(".highcharts-data-labels path").hide();
```

Comment: Tried your solution, but both of them don't work, might be something to do with the angular directive that is creating the charts. I will still try and do a work around, will let you know, but this seems as it might be the right solution.

Comment: Got it to work, called it after entire view was loaded.